# Pythonic way of using getters and setters

Tags: python, django

I would like a Pythonic way of accomplishing the following task. **To call a method in Campaign Model that returns a URL with the campaign ID and the current login user ID** i.e. `/campaign_id/user_id`

To achieve this I need the `request.user` scope, but I don't think its a good idea to have this directly in my models. I have been reading Python can use getters and setters, would this be useful? So my idea is to have something like this...

```
campaign = Campaign.object.get(id=1)
campaign.set_current_user(request.user)

referral_url = campaign.get_referral_url()

which would give me /campaign_id/user_id/
```

Is this a good way?

**My Model so far:**

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

   @property
   def current_user(self):
       return self._current_user

   @current_user.setter
   def current_user(self, user_object):
      if user_object:
          return user_object.id
      else:
          return None


   def _build_referral_url(self):
        """
        Builds the full referral URL for the user.
        :return:
        """
        return self.name + "/" + self.current_user


    def get_referral_url(self):
        """
        :return: Campaign referral URL.
        """
        return self._build_referral_url()
```

Comment: What is `set_current_user` doing? How is the user referenced from the Campaign model? If you have a foreign key, you should show it.

Comment: Please give more context. Why would you want to place the user ID in the URL?

Comment: @Kos updated code in OP. When I load campaign in my view I want to be able to get a custom link off the model which is build using the current login user. the user is not linked to the model nor do I want to access the request scope in the model. This is the best way I can think of at the moment.

Comment: But you haven't explained why you would do that. You always know the current user (it's in `request.user`), so what's the point of putting the ID in the URL, especially as you say the user isn't linked to the campaign at all. Why do all this `current_user` stuff?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman good point. I was thinking that I could use a model method and later on make the URL more complicated. So its more of a function I need thats builds a URL based on values passed. But maybe you are right and I'm overthinking this.

Comment: Since you tagged the question `Django` you probably want to know about the `reverse` function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse 

There's also a convention in Django to name the method get_absolute_url, in your case that would probably take a user object as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
def get_referral_url(self):
```

simply define:

```
def get_referral_url_for(self, user):
```

This looks the most straightforward, and doesn't give a false impression that `user` in question would be somehow permanently connected to the `Campaign`.

Comment: ok so just have one method i..e  def get_campaign_url_for_user(self, user):